# GWT: Competing Events ( Blur / Selection )

Tags: gwt

I have a tree containing data and some widgets for editing data from a single tree node. The data for the tree nodes will be updated if one of the widgets looses focus ( BlurHandler ). If an other node is selected, the widgets will be updated, showing the data for the selected tree node ( SelectionHandler ).

My problem is:

If i'm done with editing the widgets content and choose immediately a new tree node, the events ( onSelection and onBlur ) are fired in no clear defined order. Testing with Firefox, the event order is onBlur > onSelection. In IE, Chrome and Safari the order is onSelection > onBlur.

So does anybody know if i can clearly define a event order? Or does anybody had a similar problem and can tell me how i can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the body of the handler for the event that you want to go **second**, put the following:

```
Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new Scheduler.ScheduledCommand() {
    @Override
    public void execute() {
        // Your action goes here
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, already had the answer but forgot to answer here. Now you've got the points :)